# ADXL345 Interrupt issues

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I'm using a Wemos D1 Mini together with an ADXL345.
I'm using the Sparkfun library for Arduino and are able to read (via I2C) accelerations in all directions and use the interrupt routines. However, I'm not able to ge the interrupt pin (INT1) on the ADXL345 to work.
It only outputs "1"...

What I'm trying to achieve, is to get the interrupt (INT1) to output "1" when activity is detected and "0" the rest of the time.

I've made a simple code (based on examples from Sparkfun):

```
#include <SparkFun_ADXL345.h>         // SparkFun ADXL345 Library
#include <Wire.h>


const int inputPin = D5;     // Use D5 on Wemos D1 Mini as input pin
int inputPinState = 0;


/*********** COMMUNICATION SELECTION ***********/
/*    Comment Out The One You Are Not Using    */
//ADXL345 adxl = ADXL345(10);           // USE FOR SPI COMMUNICATION, ADXL345(CS_PIN);
ADXL345 adxl = ADXL345();             // USE FOR I2C COMMUNICATION

/****************** INTERRUPT ******************/
/*      Uncomment If Attaching Interrupt       */

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);                 // Start the serial terminal
  Serial.println("ADXL345 Interrupt Test");
  Serial.println();

  // initialize input pin:
  pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);

  setupADXL();

}


/****************** MAIN CODE ******************/
/*     Accelerometer Readings and Interrupt    */
void loop(){

  inputPinState = digitalRead(inputPin); 
  Serial.println(inputPinState);
  ADXL_ISR();

}  

/******************** SETUP ********************/
/*          Configure ADXL345 Settings         */

void setupADXL(){
  adxl.powerOn();                     // Power on the ADXL345

  adxl.setRangeSetting(2);           // Give the range settings
                                      // Accepted values are 2g, 4g, 8g or 16g
                                      // Higher Values = Wider Measurement Range
                                      // Lower Values = Greater Sensitivity

  adxl.setSpiBit(0);                  // Configure the device to be in 4 wire SPI mode when set to '0' or 3 wire SPI mode when set to 1
                                      // Default: Set to 1
                                      // SPI pins on the ATMega328: 11, 12 and 13 as reference in SPI Library 

  adxl.setActivityXYZ(1, 0, 0);       // Set to activate movement detection in the axes "adxl.setActivityXYZ(X, Y, Z);" (1 == ON, 0 == OFF)
  adxl.setActivityThreshold(15);      // 62.5mg per increment   // Set activity   // Inactivity thresholds (0-255)

  adxl.setInactivityXYZ(1, 0, 0);     // Set to detect inactivity in all the axes "adxl.setInactivityXYZ(X, Y, Z);" (1 == ON, 0 == OFF)
  adxl.setInactivityThreshold(15);    // 62.5mg per increment   // Set inactivity // Inactivity thresholds (0-255)
  adxl.setTimeInactivity(5);         // How many seconds of no activity is inactive?

  /* Not needed in this project 
  //adxl.setTapDetectionOnXYZ(0, 0, 0); // Detect taps in the directions turned ON "adxl.setTapDetectionOnX(X, Y, Z);" (1 == ON, 0 == OFF)

  /* Not needed in this project 
  // Set values for what is considered a TAP and what is a DOUBLE TAP (0-255)
  adxl.setTapThreshold(50);           // 62.5 mg per increment
  adxl.setTapDuration(15);            // 625 μs per increment
  adxl.setDoubleTapLatency(80);       // 1.25 ms per increment
  adxl.setDoubleTapWindow(200);       // 1.25 ms per increment
  */

  /* Not needed in this projec 
  // Set values for what is considered FREE FALL (0-255)
  adxl.setFreeFallThreshold(7);       // (5 - 9) recommended - 62.5mg per increment
  adxl.setFreeFallDuration(30);       // (20 - 70) recommended - 5ms per increment
  */


  // Setting "activity" to take place on INT1 pin
  adxl.setImportantInterruptMapping(2, 2, 2, 1, 2);     // Sets "adxl.setEveryInterruptMapping(single tap, double tap, free fall, activity, inactivity);" 
                                                        // Accepts only 1 or 2 values for pins INT1 and INT2. This chooses the pin on the ADXL345 to use for Interrupts.
                                                        // This library may have a problem using INT2 pin. Default to INT1 pin.

  // Turn on Interrupts for each mode (1 == ON, 0 == OFF)
  adxl.InactivityINT(0);
  adxl.ActivityINT(1);
  adxl.FreeFallINT(0);
  adxl.doubleTapINT(0);
  adxl.singleTapINT(0);

//attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), ADXL_ISR, RISING);   // Attach Interrupt
}


void ADXL_ISR() {


  byte interrupts = adxl.getInterruptSource();

  // Activity
  if(adxl.triggered(interrupts, ADXL345_ACTIVITY)){
    Serial.println("*** ACTIVITY ***"); 
     //add code here to do when activity is sensed
   }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular accelerometer, but you generally have to read an interrupt status register in the device to get it to deassert the interrupt pin.  How else would it know that the interrupt was actually received?

Comment: Thanx for the comments. I added a read-interrupt-function (taken from the Sparkfun example) and now it's apparently working (get it to trigger 95% of the time). I've updated the code above.